# Evaporator fan motor specifications

Tags: motor

I have an old fridge evaporator fan motor and cannot figure out what "in" in the specifications mean.[image]

I ordered a replacment motor and it does not have "in" in the specifications and after installation the fridge does not provide cool air in the fridge compartment. All the other specifications are the same.

Comment: probably spinning in wrong direction

Comment: It's unlikely to be of significance if the motor is of identical size, wiring, voltage, power. What's more likely is that whatever condition that caused you to replace the old motor is still persisting or caused further damage to something else.

Comment: It is very likely that the motor was manufactured specifically for the fridge manufacturer. The meaning of the markings on the label may be known only to the motor manufacturer, the fridge manufacturer, UL and CSA.

Comment: I'd interpret that 'in' as shorthand for 'input' - i.e. 115v, 60Hz input required with a maximum of 3.3W power draw. Don't know what 'Z.P.' is for though.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The Z.P. is short for impedance protected.